# How to add a positive integer constraint to a integer column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, constraints

How can we add a constraint which enforces a column to have only positive values.

Tried the following mysql statement but it doesn't work

```
create table test ( test_column integer CONSTRAINT blah > 0);
```

Comment: If you have MySQL 8.0.16 (MariaDB 10.2.1) or newer, you can use a `CHECK` constraint. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57167445/244297) for an example.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You would use the keyword `unsigned` to signify that the integer doesn't allow a "sign" (i.e. - it can only be positive):

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    test_column int(11) unsigned
);
```

You can read more about the numeric data types (signed & unsigned) [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html).

As far as an actual *constraint* to prevent the insertion-of negative values, MySQL has a [`CHECK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) clause that can be used in the `CREATE TABLE` statement, however, according to the documentation:

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

For reference, here is how you would use it (and though it will execute absolutely fine, it just does nothing - as the manual states):

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    test_column int(11) unsigned CHECK (test_column > 0)
);
```

**UPDATE** (rejecting negative values completely)
I've noticed from a few of your comments that you want queries with negative values to be completely rejected and not set to `0` (as a normal transaction into an `unsigned` column would do). There is no constraint that can do this in-general (that I know of, at least), however, if you turn strict-mode on (with [`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables)) any query that inserts a negative value into an unsigned column will fail with an error (along with any-other data-insertion errors, such as an invalid `enum` value).

You can test it by running the following command prior to your insert-commands:

```
SET @@SESSION.sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';
```

And if it works for you, you can either update your MySQL config with `sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES"` or use `SET @@GLOBAL.sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';` (I'm not sure if the `SET` command will affect the global mysql config though, so it may be better to update the actual config-file).

Comment: `unsigned` <> positive. `unsigned` == not negative.

Answer (score 6):

As of MySQL [8.0.16](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-16.html) (MariaDB [10.2.1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-1021-release-notes/)), [`CHECK` constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) are enforced. (In earlier versions constraint expressions were accepted in the syntax but ignored).

Therefore you can use:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    test_column INT CHECK (test_column > 0)
);
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    test_column INT,
    CONSTRAINT test_column_positive CHECK (test_column > 0)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to fix this is to explicitly tell MySQL Server to create an Unsigned integer.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_example ( 
example_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
example_num INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
example_text TEXT 
PRIMARY KEY (`example_id`) 
);
```

Comment: This is what I get when I run below statements on my local mysql server


    `mysql> insert into world values (-2);`
    `Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)`

Answer (score 1):

just use `unsigned` to allow only positive values.

```
CREATE TABLE hello 
(
    world int unsigned
);
```

- [**SQLFiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10304)

*uncomment the line and you will see the error saying: **Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'world' at row 1:***

Comment: But unsigned type still allows you to insert negative integers (it converts negative integers to zero). It does throw a warning, but query still passes

Comment: This is what I get when I run below statements on my local mysql server


    `mysql> insert into world values (-2);`
    `Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)`

Comment: Unsigned allows 0

Answer (score 0):

You should use UNSIGNED INTEGER data type.  For more information, [click here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html)